# How to list wordpress categories id and name inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is my code to get categories ids and names:

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category):
    $catids = $category->term_id;
    $catname = $category->name;
endforeach;
?>
```

Now, I want to list ids and names inside array:

```
array(
    $catids => $catname,
);
```

I want the array to be like:

```
array(
    '1' => 'Ctegory 1',
    '2' => 'Ctegory 2',
    '3' => 'Ctegory 3',
);
```

which is 1,2,3 are categories ids and Ctegory 1, Ctegory 2, Ctegory 3 are categories names

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
<?php
$order_options = array('all' => 'All Categories');
$categories = get_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category):
    $catids = $category->term_id;
    $catname = $category->name;
    $order_options[$catids] = $catname;
endforeach;

print_r($order_options);
```

And if you want to generate a dropdown of categories with `$order_options` you can use it like this:

```
<select name="">
    <?php foreach ($order_options as $cat_id => $cat_name)
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat_id ?>"><?php $cat_name ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the array to be like:
array(
 '1' => 'Ctegory 1',
 '2' => 'Ctegory 2',
 '3' => 'Ctegory 3',
);
which is 1,2,3 are categories ids and Ctegory 1, Ctegory 2, Ctegory 3 are categories names

Comment: @hazemhazem: yes that how you will get it.

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear, that is my full code, I hope you can help with it, I want to list all categories inside select: <?php 
$categories = get_categories( 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );  
foreach ( $categories as $category ): 
$catslug = $category->term_id;
$catnme =  $category->name; 
endforeach;

$order_options = array(
 'all' => 'All Categories',
 $catslug => $catnme,
);

foreach( $order_options as $value => $label ) {
 echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['cat'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
}
?>

Comment: @hazemhazem: so you want a category dropdown, right?

Comment: Yes, dropdown using $order_options = array( 'all' => 'All Categories', $catslug => $catnme, ); I want to extract ids inside $catslug and names inside $catnme to get the final result : $order_options = array(
    'all' => 'All Categories',  '1' => 'Ctegory 1',
    '2' => 'Ctegory 2',
    '3' => 'Ctegory 3',
);